# how to use variable datas outside useeffect in threejs

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-hooks, three.js, react-functional-component

I'm using three.js in react and I need to use animate function on outside of useeffect
here I attached some codes
[image]

need to get updated value of the variable to use it on other functions

Comment: Please don't [use images for code, data structures or log files](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9078341)

Comment: "_value of the variable_" - Which variable? "_I need to use animate function on outside of useeffect_" - What `animate` function?

Comment: camera,scene,controls,model1,mixer1,renderer,clock

Comment: it sounds like you are describing a race condition. You are setting those variables, but you are doing so asynchronously - after the page render. Sounds as if you are attempting to run your animation during the rendering process with `undefined` variables. You'll need to run your animation within the `useEffect()` method (or within a `useCallback()`